# Image from imagePicker just won't show in my imageView

Tags: ios, swift, image, uiimageview, uiimagepickercontroller

I have a viewController in my app, that opens with the camera being called. When the user takes a photo and presses 'use photo', the image should be shown in the same viewController's imageView.

I know it may seem as a duplicate(!) - but I read lots of questions in here about showing images from the imagePicker and so far none of their solutions have worked for me.

Basically I get no errors, neither in the console or in the code. - But when I run the app on my device, it freezes after pressing 'use photo' and then I have to shut down the app.

My only idea right now is that there is some general privacy ussage setting or something like that, which I need to set in order to show the user's photos, but in that case I don't know which and how!

Please help!

Code:

```
class CreateNewPerson: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate,
UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var personPhoto: UIImageView!
    let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()

    override func viewDidAppear (_ animated: Bool) {
        checkCameraPermissions()
        super.viewDidAppear(true)
    }

    private func checkCameraPermissions() {
        let status = AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatus(for: .video)
        switch status {
        case .authorized: self.presentPicker()
        case .notDetermined: self.requestAccess()
        case .denied: print("Permission denied.")
        case .restricted: print("Permission restricted.")
        }
    }

    private func requestAccess() {
        AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: AVMediaType.video) { granted in
            if !granted {
                print("Error.")
            } else {
                self.checkCameraPermissions()
            }
        }
    }

    private func presentPicker() {
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = .camera
        present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    private func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : UIImage]) {
        let chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        personPhoto.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        personPhoto.image = chosenImage
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

So yeah - basically it's just the last method that really is the issue! The camera shows and all, but I can't show the photo.. What's wrong with my approach?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since you just need to present iOS standard image picker, there is no need for `AVCaptureDevice` with those permissions or even `import AVFoundation` at all!

```
class CreateNewPerson: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate,
UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var personPhoto: UIImageView!
    let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()

    private func presentPicker() {
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = .camera
        present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    // Swift 4.2
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        let chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as! UIImage
        personPhoto.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        personPhoto.image = chosenImage
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    /*
    // Swift 4.1
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        let chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
        personPhoto.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        personPhoto.image = chosenImage
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    */
}
```